# insertAdjcentHTML is not working in JsDOM?

Tags: javascript, jsdom

When I try to use `insertAdjacentElement` and `insertAdjacentHTML` is not working in jsdom. I'm using jsdom 11.11.0. I'm trying like this

```
var DOMEle = document.getElementById('#test');
DOMEle.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',htmlElement);
```

I'm getting an error like `insertAdjacentElement` is not defined. How I can fix this error in jsdom. please help me.

Comment: It's not an error; it just hasn't been implemented: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting an error like insertAdjacentElement is not defined.

This is because JSDom does not support those methods.

> How I can fix this error in jsdom.

[Fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) the [JSDom source code](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). Add the feature to the library. Make a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) to ask for your changes to be added to JSDom.